# Selecting and Updating using variables

Tags: mysql

I have to perform the UPDATE and SELECT Operations based on variables that's been set from the query.

```
SET @var1:=(SELECT table_name 
            FROM information_schema.tables 
            WHERE table.schema='db1' AND table_name like
                 (select tc from db2.tab1 where col1='test')
           );
```

@var1 returns a table name

```
UPDATE @var1 SET col2='Test' WHERE 1=1;
```

But i get error near @var1

I really need to pass the @var1 to update statement. How do i proceed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL does not like the dynamic SQL. You will need to use a prepared statement, such as

```
set @s = CONCAT( ' UPDATE ',@var1,  'SET ......); -- your query

PREPARE stmt1 FROM @s; 
EXECUTE stmt1; 
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
```